# Looking ahead in Lists with list comprehension

Tags: haskell

I am having some trouble using list comprehension in Haskell. My question is how do you look ahead in a list when using list comprehension. For example: say I have a list `[1,2,3,4,5]` as an argument to the list comprehension function. This function has to build the new list from this list, but the condition is that if the next element is the same then do not include that element in the list.

```
build [] = []
build list = [x | x <- list, (if current element equal next ignore)]
```

So the list `[1,1,2,3,4,4,4]` will output `[1,2,3]`

Any help appreciated

Comment: why not `[1,2,3,4]`?

Comment: One way would be to `zip` the list with itself minus the first element. However this would require a `zip_longest` function instead of `zip`. In python that function is available, and so you can write `[x for x,y in zip_longest(xs, xs[1:]) if x != y]`, however I don't think there is a `zip_longest` equivalent in Haskell. At least not a polymorphic one that could guarantee correct results (you cannot use an element of a list as default value in this case).

Comment: How should it behave with the last element of the list (since there is no next element)?

Comment: Do you really need to use a list comprehension? `build = map head . group` seems much simpler.

Comment: Ok so, answering Sassa NF question it is not [1,2,3,4] because the function is supposed to work like this. Compare 1 with 1 (they are the same) so ignore. Move along one, compare 1 with 2 (they are different), include 1 in the list. Move along one, compare 2 with 3 (they are different) include 2 in the list etc.

Comment: Answering shang question, the last element is never included because there is no next element to compare.

Comment: @ShaunvanBurick keep explaining to the end. Don't you find it strange that the last 4 and 4 you do compare and skip the penultimate 4, but then to make the decision about the last 4, you need the element after it, but there are none.

Answer (score 2):

by not including 4 in the output it seems you're always dropping the last element.  If that's the case this is what you're looking for:

```
build xs =  [x | (x,y) <- zip xs $ tail xs, x/=y]
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution provided. I think that you cleared it up for me because I was getting confused that in list comprehension it expects a bool or test. I never thought to use the methods provided by you or Sassa NF.

Answer (score 1):

One better, if `4` was meant to be included in the example (I don't see why not):

```
build [] = []
build xs@(x:_) = x:[y | (x:y:_) <- tails xs, x/=y]
```